# How to read a Qubit rotation lookup table?

Tags: mathematics

In [A New Quantum Inspired Genetic Algorithma](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1490730) a lookup table is used to decide the Qubit rotation. But how the lookup table is used is not briefed.

Does anyone know how it is done ?

An example is shown below.

> $\delta\theta$ is chosen equal to $\pi/25$. The following table gives the value of the rotation angle in function of $\alpha, \beta$ and the bit's value in the best solution.
>
> $$\text{Table 1. Lookup table of the rotation angle}$$
> $$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}\hline \boldsymbol\alpha & \boldsymbol\beta & \textbf{Reference bit value} & \textbf{Angle} \\ \hline >0 & >0 & 1 & +\delta\theta \\ \hline >0 & >0 & 0 & -\delta\theta \\ \hline >0 & <0 & 1 & -\delta\theta \\ \hline >0 & <0 & 0 & +\delta\theta \\ \hline <0 & >0 & 1 & -\delta\theta \\ \hline <0 & >0 & 0 & +\delta\theta \\ \hline <0 & <0 & 1 & +\delta\theta \\ \hline <0 & <0 & 0 & -\delta\theta \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Comment: Can you add the link to the reference paper? I am not sure how they use it here.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1490730/

Comment: A start is that it appears you're looking up whether you're rotating the qubit by $+\pi/25$ or $-\pi/25$, based on the value of $\alpha, \beta$ and the 'reference bit value' but anything more than that requires more knowledge of the algorithm than I have